# Output cache in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

How can I get the dropbox items in cache, in MVC?

I have tried the following, but it calls the page function each time.

What could be the issue or the right way to do it?

Please suggest.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server,
      NoStore = true, Order = 0)]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetRegions()
    {
```

Comment: Doesn't `NoStore = true` tell the framework to NOT store the cached items (when using server side cache) = have to generate the result every time?

Comment: I have tried already, if i put the code in controller it works but it is not possible for me to keep the code there

Comment: ahhh. you can't put the attribute anywhere but in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it in your controller on those actions there

Comment: it is not in the controller, it is a seperate project of sqlite archit. and where system.web.mvc is added as reference

Comment: The thing is i am not able to use on controller due to code issues in my project. This is a normal class file

Comment: If you have large amounts of data, use an autocomplete using json instead that limits the amount of data sent to client.