# Cache dropbox items in MVC razor. How to do that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

How can i cache my items and values for dropdown list in MVC?

Is there a way to do so?

I am doing that in controller.

Sample code is.......

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RegionTasks regionTasks = new RegionTasks();
        ViewBag.Region = GetRegions();}
```

My controller has function as below.

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 10, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetRegions()
    {
        RegionTasks regionTasks = new RegionTasks();
       return regionTasks.GetRegions();
    }
```

I have tested and it not caches the item for region.

How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output cache in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784914/output-cache-in-mvc)

Comment: Why do you ask the exact same question again?

Comment: Probably `OutputCache` only works on an `ActionResult`, and your Duration is set to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darin is also right, how ever i have done following code to store on server for X minutes.

```
 private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGlobalUrlRegion(string profileName)
    {
        string cacheKey = "cacheUrlRegion";
        RegionTasks regionTasks = RegionTasks.CreateRegionTasks();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> regionUrlList = HttpContext.Cache[cacheKey] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
        if (regionUrlList == null)
        {
            var regionObject = regionTasks.GetRegions(profileName);
            var cTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GlobalCacheDurationInMin"].ToString()));
            var cExp = System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
            var cPri = System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal;
            regionUrlList = regionObject;
            HttpContext.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, regionObject, null, cTime, cExp, cPri, null);
        }

        return regionUrlList;
    }
```

Comment: Cheers, vote up. One problem I had (with a similar implementation) was that my equivalent of `regionUrlList` was being set, but I couldn't seem to read the value on the first run, resulting in an exception. It did skip over the `if` block on the second run however, and the correct value was returned. My approach was to initialise (my equivalent of) `regionObject` as `null` before the `if` block, then use something like this for the return - `return (regionObject != null) ? regionObject : regionUrlList`. That way a value should be returned, even if it is not yet in the cache for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

The `OutputCache` attribute is used on controller actions to cache the resulting output. It has strictly no effect on other methods.

If you want to cache custom objects you could use the `HttpContext.Cache`:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetRegions()
{
    var regionTasks = HttpContext.Cache["regions"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
    if (regionTasks == null)
    {
        // nothing in the cache => we perform some expensive query to
        // fetch the result
        regionTasks = new RegionTasks().GetRegions();

        // and we cache it so that the next time we don't need to perform
        // the query
        HttpContext.Cache["regions"] = regionTasks;
    }

    return regionTasks;
}
```

The `regionTasks` are now cached under the `regions` key and accessible from anywhere in your ASP.NET application which has access to the `HttpContext.Cache`.